# How to share default params for $resource between multiple $factory inside angular module?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have an angular module that does server API's.
It looks like:

```
angular.module('mongoAPI', ['ngResource', 'security'])
    .run(['authService', runMongoAPI])
    .factory('factory1', ['$resource', '$http', 'CONSTANTS', 'authService', shopFactoryCtrl])
    .factory('factory2', ['$resource', '$http', 'CONSTANTS', 'authService', accountFactoryCtrl])
    .factory('factory3', ['$resource', '$http', 'CONSTANTS', 'authService', segmentFactoryCtrl])
    .factory('factory4', ['$resource', '$http', 'CONSTANTS', 'authService', productFactoryCtrl])
```

All factories need an id from authservice to build the resource URL:

```
function runMongoAPI(authService, $provide) {
    var defaultParams = {
        shopId: authService.id
    }
    $provide.value('APIDefaults', defaultParams);
```

}

Inside each factory I have similar to:

```
function integrationsFactoryCtrl($resource, $http, CONSTANTS, authService, APIDefaults) {
    var actions = {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false,
            params: {
                service: '@service',
                action: '@action'
            }
        }
    }
    var res = $resource('http://myserver.com/' + '/:shopId/integrations/:service/:action', APIDefaults, actions);
    return res;

}
```

I would like shopId to be shared between all $resources from default params.. How is that possible?